# Stack with push and pop functions not working

Tags: c++, null, crash, stack

This is the program.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct stack
{
    int inf;
    stack* link;
} *start, *p;

void push(stack*, stack*, int);
void pop(stack*, stack*);

int main()
{
    int s = 0;
    string thing;

    cin >> thing;
    while (thing != "end")
    {
        if (thing == "push")
        {
            push(start, p, s);
        }
        if (thing == "pop")
        {
            pop(start, p);
        }
        cin >> thing;
    }
    return 0;

}

void push(stack *start, stack *p, int s)
{

        cin >> s;

        p = start;
        start = new stack;
        start->inf = s;
        start->link = p;

        cout << "pushed " << start->inf << endl;
}

void pop(stack *start, stack *p)
{


    cout << "popped " << start->inf;
    p = start;
    start = start->link;
    delete p;


}
```

It's a simple program to allow me to push and pop items to and from a stack, but for some reason the `pop()` just won't work. If I add an `if(start)` before the `pop` it just skips it, making me think that the stack somehow becomes NULL after `push` is completed. Basically everything works until it reaches the `cout << "popped " << start->inf;` line, when it just crashes (no error message) which again makes me think the stack becomes null before it reaches `pop()`. Any suggestions?

Comment: The logic of push looks like you can keep track of only two pushes at max.You need to rethink of logic.

Comment: You are passing your pointers by value. So after running push start and p are unchanged in main().

Comment: in this code `start` is a pointer initialized by `NULL` (implicitly). Why do you expect it to be non-null?

Comment: You pass in pointers, but if you want to change the value of the pointer inside the function, you need to pass in a pointer or reference to the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, both of your function's signature are weird:

```
void push(stack *start, stack *p, int s)
void pop(stack *start, stack *p)
```

Assuming `start` points to top of stack, you should discard `p`. It should be a local variable to the function, not a parameter.

Second, let's see `push` implementation:

```
p = start;
start = new stack;
start->inf = s;
start->link = p;
```

this one looks ALMOST good. What you missed is that `start` is declared as a pointer to stack, and you are changing the pointer inside the function, which is a value parameter instead of a reference. With your current signature, you can change what `start` POINTS TO, but not `start` itself.
You can either declare it as pointer to pointer to stack, and change the body accordingly (you need double dereference for assigning `inf` and `link`) or use reference parameter by adding `&` before the parameter name. The same case applies to your `pop` function.

Comment: I had a bit of a tough time understanding it but with the help of @Valeri Atamaniouk i got it. Chaning "stack *start" to "stack *&start" (and all other accordingly) fixed the problem, thank you. I got confused since a friend told me that when you use a pointer parameter, it is automatically used as a reference just like arrays are (you dont have to put& infront of the array parameter in order for the changed to be remembered outside the function), but i guess it doesnt aply to pointers?

Comment: @user3455974  think of pointers as a variable that contains an address. `stack *p` passes in an address. The function gets a copy of that address. If you want to change that address inside the function, you have to go a step further and provide the address of that address. Taking a reference to the pointer, `stack * & p`, is preferred here over  a pointer to a pointer, `stack **p`, because & provides protective restrictions to how you can supply and use the address.

Answer (score 0):

Here how you make reference of pointer:

```
void push(stack*&, stack*&, int);
void pop(stack*&, stack*&);
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct, but they aren't really explaining why.

The start and p used here

```
void push(stack *start, stack *p, int s)
```

Are not the same as those defined here.

```
struct stack
{
    int inf;
    stack* link;
} *start, *p;
```

`push` has a whole new start and p which may be copies of the other start and p, but they are not the same. Push could be defined

```
void push(stack *hamburger, stack *cheeseburger, int s)
```

with corresponding changes to the variables used inside the functions and you would see no difference in the behaviour of the function.

What you would get in the burger version of `push` is the ability to see the original `start` and `p`. Because allowing two variables with the same name at the same time would lead to total confusion (seriously, which one gets used?) the inner-most definition hides all outer definitions. So not only is `push`'s `start` not the globally defined `start`, but `push`'s `start` is blocking access to global `start`.

However, if you define and don't change the contents

```
void push(stack *hamburger, stack *cheeseburger, int s)
{
    cin >> s;

    p = start;
    start = new stack;
    start->inf = s;
    start->link = p;

    cout << "pushed " << start->inf << endl;
}
```

`hamburger` and `cheeseburger` aren't used for anything and `push` uses the global `start` and `p`

Now think about what happens if someone modifies your code and leaves out `p` by mistake.

```
void push(stack *start, int s)
```

`p` is still a valid variable, the code still happily compiles, and it uses the wrong `p`.

Consider carefully before reusing variable names. I like to tag global variables so I can see when they are being used and so they are less likely to collide with locals. For me, start would be gStart. It looks odd enough to stand out and unlikely to be used by accident.

OP's code's not bad. Needed a test for valid integer input and for popping of empty stack

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct stack
{
    int inf;
    stack* link;
} *gStart; // don't need p at all start renamed to avoid collisions

void push(stack * & start)
{
    stack *p; //just holds a temporary no need to pass
    int s; // same as above

    while (!(cin >> s)) // read and test the input        
    { // bad input. Clear stream and prompt
        cin.clear(); 
        cout << "nice try, wiseguy. Gimmie an int!" << endl;
    }

    p = new stack();
    p->inf = s;
    p->link = start;
    start = p;

    cout << "pushed " << start->inf << endl;
}

void pop(stack *& start)
{
    stack *p; //no need to pass in
    if (start != NULL)
    { // don't pop list if list empty
        cout << "popped " << start->inf << endl;
        p = start;
        start = p->link;
        delete p;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "stack empty" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // there is no need for start to be global. It could just as easily be allocated here.
    string thing;

    cin >> thing;
    while (thing != "end")
    {
        if (thing == "push")
        {
            push(gStart);
        }
        else if (thing == "pop")
        {
            pop(gStart);
        }

        cin >> thing;
    }
    return 0;
}
```